# Register for Local Notification

Tags: ios, localnotification

I am developing an IOS application with phonegap and need to set local notification for it which will repeat on every friday and specified time

Also there is requirement that user will decide to receive or not the local notification

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you read the following article on the topic which i found very helpful

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = @"Body";
        notif.alertAction = @"AlertButtonCaption";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }
}
```

This is just a basic outline of how it works but starting from this you should be able to schedule a notification.

Comment: I can schedule the notification but how to repeat it for every friday and also how to activate user registration before sending local notification